# StopIteration: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I get this error while running a keras code, so keras is trying to import

> from PIL import Image as pil_image

I have installed pillow, also I'm able to successfully import this in my python terminal but in jupyter notebook it gives import error.

env - ubuntu 16 on aws ec2 instance, I'm using aws deep learning ami for ubuntu

pillow comes with conda, I also tried to install using pip

but again I can import it in python/ipython shell but not in jupyter notebook.

Comment: I got a bug with Jupyter once that it never pointed to the right environment. User `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` to see which python your jupyter is running. Maybe you should uninstall jupyter and install it via conda in the right environment. Or just install it in the right environment first with `conda install jupyter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had opencv installed. But I just installed pillow(keeping opencv) and it worked for me.

Comment: For those who need it: the command is `pip install --ignore-installed pillow`.

Answer (score 0):

So, It seems pillow/pil was included in jesper or opencv package on jupyter notebook, so I uninstalled both jesper and opencv in package portal of notebook and installed pillow. now everything is running fine.